# Display a full image with wxHaskell

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I am using wxHaskell to display a full image in a window. My code is:

```
import Graphics.UI.WX
import Graphics.UI.WXCore

main :: IO ()
main = start testimg

testimg :: IO ()
testimg = do
  f <- frame [text := "Test Image"]
  p <- panel f []

  image <- bitmapCreateFromFile "landscape.png"
  imagep <- panel p [ on paint := onPaint image ]

  set f [ layout:= fill $ container p $ widget imagep ]

  where
    onPaint image dc rect = drawBitmap dc image pointZero True []
```

Anyway when the app runs nothing is displayed (not even the window's borders). How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `fill` before `widget imagep` with the effect that the panel you paint in the picture doesn't get any surface. And I'd recommend setting an outerSize, too. You might also want to have a look at https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell/blob/master/samples/wx/ImageViewer.hs for inspiration. Good luck!

```
import Graphics.UI.WX
import Graphics.UI.WXCore

main :: IO ()
main = start testimg

testimg :: IO ()
testimg = do
  f <- frame [text := "Test Image"]
  p <- panel f []

  image <- bitmapCreateFromFile "landscape.png"
  imagep <- panel p [ on paint := onPaint image ]

  set f [ layout:= fill $ container p $ fill $ widget imagep 
        , outerSize := sz 500 500
        ]

  where
    onPaint image dc rect = drawBitmap dc image pointZero True []
```